# SELECT INTO with CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a way to do a SELECT INTO that has a CASE statement in the select part?  I need to do some data transformation before it goes into the new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Here, #test is being copied to #testnew, where the case statement adds a * before each item with values beginning with 'f':

```
create table #test(id int, item1 varchar(10), item2 varchar(10))
insert into #test values(1,'foo','bar')
, (2,'fud','fudge')
go

select t.id
, item1=case when left(item1,1)='f' then '*'+item1 else item1 end
, item2=case when left(item2,1)='f' then '*'+item2 else item2 end
into #testnew
from #test t
go

select * from #testnew;
go

drop table #test;
drop table #testnew;
go
```

Result:

```
id          item1       item2
----------- ----------- -----------
1           *foo        bar
2           *fud        *fudge
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can:

```
SELECT CASE SourceField WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS SourceField
INTO DestinationTable
FROM SourceTable
```

Comment: You need the END keyword, right? ELSE 'No' END AS SourceField

Comment: indeed, AdaTheDev where's the `END` ? ^^

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Be sure to name the column. Also be sure you cast the value of the Case statement to an explicit type to avoid problems.

```
SELECT
    Cast((
        Case(ID)
            When (1) Then 'Text'
            Else NULL
        End) as varchar(50)
    ) as NewColumn
INTO #TempTable
FROM MyTable
```